# Selecting a group with or without certain conditions across many rows in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have data like this:

```
ID     SomeVar
123      0
123      1
123      2
234      1
234      2
234      3
456      3
567      0
567      1
```

I'm trying to group by my ID to to return all of the IDs that do not have a record with the value `0`. That is, my selection would look like this:

```
ID
234
456
```

Is there an easy way to do this without creating a subset table with all records not containing 0 then joining it back to the full data set where the tables don't match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally try to avoid subqueries, but you could use one for this case.  Do the same group by, and check that the id isn't in a subquery of ids that have 0 for SomeVar.  In this case, distinct will do the same and more efficiently, so I'll do that first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM [table_name]
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM [table_name] WHERE SomeVar = 0
);
```

And if you want to get other information by using a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ID, max(SomeVar), count(*), sum(SomeVar)
FROM [table_name]
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM [table_name] WHERE SomeVar = 0
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Any particular reason you try to avoid sub queries?

Comment: @DukeLuke, if you are dealing with large amounts of data, it is often inefficient.  It can also typically be done with a left join and a condition that checks for nulls, but not in this case.  As long as you don't have a massive data set, your case is exactly what subqueries are good for.

Comment: @mtr.web In Hive NOT IN subquery will work the same as LEFT JOIN + WHERE is NULL filter. Your solution  is table scan two times + join+ distinct aggregation. Aggregation + HAVING filter is more performant solution. Subqueries are not bad. Joins and extra scans are bad.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(somevar) > 0;
```

This assumes that `somevar` is never negative.  If that is a possibility, then you can use the slightly more verbose:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when somevar = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use case statement with count or sum aggregation, filter by count using `having`:

```
select ID  
  from
      ( 
       select ID, count(case when SomeVar=0 then 1 end) cnt
         from mytable
        group by ID having count(case when SomeVar=0 then 1 end) = 0 
      ) s
;
```